# Android sharedpref ringtone giving address instead of name

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, ringtone

I am trying to develop an application in Android. I am using SharedPreferences to set default values of Ringtone. When I try to get the default notification, instead of giving me name, it gives me address (for e.g. content://settings/system/notification_sound). I want a name for ringtone instead of the address.

Can anyone help me out for this?

```
public class Preferences {

    private static final String DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION = "defaultNotification";
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    Context context;

    /**
     * Default Constructor - Requires an android.content.Context 
     * @param context
     */
    public Preferences(Context context) {
        /* Use "this" for most Activity Contexts */
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        this.context = context;
    }


    public String getDefaultNotification() {
        return preferences.getString(
                context.getString(R.string.strSettingsNotification), 
                DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION);
    }

    public void setDefaultNotification(String notification) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(
                context.getString(R.string.strSettingsNotification), 
                notification);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

In one of the Activity class, I am getting default notification using preferences.getDefaultNotification();

Comment: @j Modi post your code here..so we can help to solve your issue..

Comment: @SDROID Risk, code added above..

Comment: @Dev, code added above..